# Hibernate restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, restrictions

I have a class named as `Films` and it has `id`, `filmName`, `actionStatus` and so on. I want to take the `filmName`s where its `actionStatus=4`. There are many `filmName`s with `actionStatus=4`.

I tried to do it this way:

```
 Session ses = model.DBManager.getInstance().getSession();
 List<Films> film_list;
 Criteria criFilm = ses.createCriteria(Films.class);
 criFilm.add(Restrictions.eq("actionStatus", 4));
 film_list = criFilm.list();

 for (Films films : film_list) {
     System.out.println("film details " + films.getFilmName());
 }
```

I'm not getting the required outputs by the above code.

Please help.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception. Always. And post the relevant code: the Films entity (which should be named `Film` BTW).

Comment: Hi, Is actionStatus is a class reference or field?